# Write data with special chars/quotation into CSV, using python

Tags: python, csv

My data, that I have in a Python list, can contain quotes, etc.:

```
the Government's
projections`
indexation" that
```

Now I'd like to write it into a CSV file but it seems the special chars "break" the CSV structure.

```
csv.register_dialect('doublequote', quotechar='"', delimiter=';', quoting=csv.QUOTE_ALL)

with open ( 'csv_data.csv', 'r+b' ) as f:
    header = next (csv.reader(f))
    dict_writer = csv.DictWriter(f, header, -999, dialect='doublequote')
    dict_writer.writerow(csv_data_list)
```

It usually can write up to the first 50 lines or so.
I tried to delete the next row from the source list and it wrote to 60 lines. 
Is there any "better" way of writing all sorts of data into a CSV?

I'm trying sth like this:

```
data['title'] = data['title'].replace("'", '`' )
```

but that doesn't seem to be right?

Comment: Using the same file for writing and reading may be a problem. Trying writing to a new file.

Comment: Could you use a completely different delimiter/sep, say a tab `\t` ?

Comment: @CMorris That is possible - but I'm more worried about the quotechar, since I've got quotechars in my data.

Comment: "Break" how?  Provide a [minimal complete verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) illustrating the problem.  Also the solution varies for Python 2.x and 3.x. What version?

Comment: Using the default settings (i.e. no dialect), have you tried loading the "broken" CSV file into an application such as Excel? You will probably find it is displayed correctly.

Comment: Yes - I tried to load the files into LibreOffice Calc. 
Currently I'm using the export function from MongoDB after creating a new collection for my data. The whole program is rather complex with several layers of logic and data and the minimal example was difficult to create.